# Achieving rolling image effect?

Tags: image, flash

I am a newbie in designing flash content. I am designing a flash movie to put up in my website. I need clouds to roll in the background. I have a cloud image, but I want it to roll in the background as below.

```
<---cloud_img
---cloud_img<
--cloud_img<-
-cloud_img<--
cloud_img<---
loud_img<---c
oud_img<---cl
```

Is it possible to achieve this kind of effect in flash. I am using swish max to develop flash. Give me some ideas to achieve this effect smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve that is to make your image doubled horizontally, and then simply scroll it from left to right. When you reach the rightmost position (whole right image is showing), reset the position to the display the whole left image. Rinse. Repeat.

You might want to apply a single-image wide mask to the movieclip/sprite/image, so the extras don't show in the display.